# Want to Merge kinect Skeleton view with kinect RGB view

Tags: .net, wpf, kinect

Hi I want to see the skeleton over the RGB video is it possible?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. This guy did it:

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Kinectize-your-application-with-the-Kinect-Control-for-WPF